# Whats does Keyboard.create() in LWJGL do?

Tags: java, lwjgl

Well I was studying the org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard class and then I saw that there were create() and destroy() methods, but what are they used for? Because I can use the Keyboard class without creating anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from the [API docs](http://www.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/input/Keyboard.html#create%28%29):

> "Create" the keyboard. The display must first have been created. The reason for this is so the keyboard has a window to "focus" in.

And from a tutorial in [this site](http://sabia.tic.udc.es/gc/Contenidos%20adicionales/trabajos/Opengl/LWJGL/entradaSalida.html) (translated from spanish):

> For the keyboard, like with the mouse, we should "initialize" the keyboard, for that we'll type `Keyboard.create()`. With this we now can continue with the keyboard's functions.

Followed by this sample:

```
Keyboard.create();
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_UP)) {       
    //Código a realizar cuando se  pulsa arriba
}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_DOWN)) {       
    //Código a realizar cuando se  pulsa abajo
}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_LEFT)) {       
    //Código a realizar cuando se  pulsa izquierda
}
if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_RIGHT)) {       
    //Código a realizar cuando se  pulsa derecha
}
```

So it basically initializes the keyboard so you can receive input from the `Keyboard` object. Same for the `destroy()` method, that would probably stop receiving input. The reason why you can use it without calling that methods may be because they were part of an older implementation and are still there for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Well, it's been a long time since I last used LWJGL and the since you say that you don't need to call them, well, maybe they're indeed useless.

Comment: Well, watching the code I noticed that it really does NOTHING it calls to a empty void in org.lwjgl.Sys

Comment: There you go, so it is just there for backwards compatibility or legacy apps.